# Inconsistent behaviour c++ classes in classes

Tags: c++

Edit based on the comments and the answer:

```
class Array {

public:
    int size;
    int *elements;

    explicit Array(int maxSize) : size(0), elements(new int[maxSize]) {}

    Array(Array &old) : elements(static_cast<int *>(malloc(sizeof(int) * size))), size(old.size) {
        memcpy(elements, old.elements, sizeof(int) * size);
    }

    Array(Array &&old) noexcept : size(old.size), elements(old.elements) {
        old.elements = nullptr;
    }

    ~Array() {
        delete[] elements;
    }

    void add(int e) {
        elements[size++] = e;
    }
};
```

```
class Base {

public:
    Array a;

    explicit Base(Array &a) : a(std::move(a)) {}
};
```

```
int main() {

    Array a(5);
    a.add(1);
    std::cout << "Address: "<< a.elements << std::endl;
    std::cout << "First element: "<< a.elements[0] << std::endl;
    Array b = std::move(a);
    std::cout << "Address: "<< b.elements << std::endl;
    std::cout << "First element: "<< b.elements[0] << std::endl;
    Base c(b);
    std::cout << "Address: "<< c.a.elements << std::endl;
    std::cout << "First element: "<< c.a.elements[0] << std::endl;

    Base *d = static_cast<Base *>(malloc(sizeof(Base) * 2));
    Array e = std::move(c.a);
    std::cout << "Address: "<< e.elements << std::endl;
    std::cout << "First element: "<< e.elements[0] << std::endl;

    new (d) Base(e);
    std::cout << "Address: "<< d[0].a.elements << std::endl;
    std::cout << "First element: "<< d[0].a.elements[0] << std::endl;
}
```

---

I am trying to make some tailored structs and classes in c++, and I am having some issues in copy constructors of classes.

What I am trying to do is to create a class in which a pointer is copied within the copy constructor and replaced with `nullpointer` in the previous object. Everything is fine until I try to do it inside another class.

In that case the first element of the array change value for no reason (I can explain).

Here is a mre:

```
class Array {

public:
    int *elements;
    int size;

    explicit Array(int maxSize) : size(0), elements(static_cast<int *>(malloc(sizeof(int) * maxSize))) {}

    Array(Array &old) : size(old.size), elements(old.elements) {
        old.elements = nullptr;
    }

    ~Array() {
        delete elements;
    }

    void add(int e) {
        elements[size++] = e;
    }
};
```

```
class Base {

public:
    Array a;

    explicit Base(Array &a) : a(a) {}
};
```

```
int main() {
    Array a(5);
    a.add(1);
    std::cout << "Address: "<< a.elements << std::endl;
    std::cout << "First element: "<< a.elements[0] << std::endl;
    Array b = a;
    std::cout << std::endl << "Old address: "<< a.elements << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Address: "<< b.elements << std::endl;
    std::cout << "First element: "<< b.elements[0] << std::endl;
    Base c(b);
    std::cout << std::endl << "Old address: "<< b.elements << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Address: "<< c.a.elements << std::endl;
    std::cout << "First element: "<< c.a.elements[0] << std::endl;
    Base *d = static_cast<Base *>(malloc(sizeof(Base) * 2));
    Array e = c.a;
    std::cout << std::endl << "Old address: "<< c.a.elements << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Address: "<< e.elements << std::endl;
    std::cout << "First element: "<< e.elements[0] << std::endl;
    d[0] = Base(e);
    std::cout << std::endl << "Old address: "<< c.a.elements << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Address: "<< d[0].a.elements << std::endl;
    std::cout << "First element: "<< d[0].a.elements[0] << std::endl;
}
```

Output:

```
Address: 0x560838558eb0
First element: 1

Old address: 0
Address: 0x560838558eb0
First element: 1

Old address: 0
Address: 0x560838558eb0
First element: 1

Old address: 0
Address: 0x560838558eb0
First element: 1

Old address: 0
Address: 0x560838558eb0
First element: 1619232088

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: `is copied within the copy constructor and replaced with nullpointer in the previous object` that looks like a job for a `move` constructor. Nobody expects a copy constructor to invalidate an object being copied

Comment: @MarekR why is it invalid? The previous object has no more a pointer to the array

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/Pna3s5Yc8

Comment: Technically not invalid, but a user of your class does a copy he will most likely not expect a move.

Comment: Read abut [Rule 3/5/0](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three)

Comment: `d[0] = Base(e);` looks like an assignment to me. That would not use the copy constructor, but an assignment operator.

Comment: @SergeyKolesnik thank you, I will change it to a move operator

Comment: @Bop you're right, I was talking about the Array copy operator, not the Base one

Comment: @FrancescoCiraolo `Base *d = static_cast<Base *>(malloc(sizeof(Base) * 2));` -- You believed you created two objects, but you didn't create anything.  Using `d` as if you actually have 2 `Base` objects is undefined behavior.  No need to go any further looking after that line in the code.

Comment: You didn't implement `operator =`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `d` object does not hold a valid array of `Base` objects. You merely allocated memory that may or may not be sufficient. But you never instantiated an object of type Base. So you cannot expect to use it.

If you need an old style array, just create it:

```
Base d[2] = {/*initialisation*/};
```

or use `new` if you need it on the free store. Usually, if you use `malloc` or its counterpart `free` in C++, you are likely doing something wrong.

Also, and not directly related, have a look at [std::exchange](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/exchange).

Comment: I need to use the malloc, so should I do like `new (d) Base(e);`?
I am using `malloc` and `free` instead of the c++ array definition because the code is will be executed in parallel and I need each array segment do be initialized by its thread.

Comment: Why don't you have a `std::vector<Base>` if you need to add individual objects during its lifetime? That's what a `std::vector` is for. Also, listen to the comments under your original post. You are introducing move semantics without implementing them in a move constructor. That's not a good idea.

Comment: Okay, if several threads access the same array, you need to allocate the memory before they start writing. You could either use a `Base[2]` if you can meaningfully default-initialise a `Base` or otherwise you may want to have a `Base*[2]`.

Comment: About the moving operator I will change it immediately, thanks.
But it is not clear to me why a `malloc` here would be so wrong, I tried with to create the object like `new (d) Base(e);` and the code is working.
I cannot use a default constructor and with Base *[n] it will not be cache efficient, so I am stuck with the `malloc`...

Comment: @FrancescoCiraolo If plan to use placement new, use [`std::aligned_storage_t`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/aligned_storage). Then you can place the object in `d[0]`. The linked page has an example how to do what you want to do correctly.

Comment: @FrancescoCiraolo *But it is not clear to me why a malloc here would be so wrong,* -- It is wrong because in C++,  it does not create an object.  The C++ compiler must be aware that objects are created, and there are several ways to do that.  Using `malloc` as you did before is *not* one of those ways.  It is just a blob of bytes, with no form to them.  As you see, you must use `new` in some form (placement-new in this case) to tell the compiler that you are actually dealing with `Base` objects, so that the compiler generates the correct code for object handling.